# Can you create a project on GitLab using ssh?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have an account with gitlab.com. I am trying to automate some of the steps of setting up a new dev server. Is it possible to connect to my account at gitlab.com via ssh and then create a new project? If so, how? If no, why not?

Currently I get this error when trying to access via ssh:

PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, User Name!
Connection to gitlab.com closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to create a project on a Gitlab server for automation purposes, I would recommend using their [REST API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/) which allows you to perform various actions on the Gitlab platform.

Among them, it is possible to create a project [owned by the authenticated user](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#create-project), or to create a project [owned by a given user](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#create-project-for-user).

Comment: Yeah yeah. I also have to wait so many minutes to accept the answer.